# C # using Http/2.0 on older OS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, windows-10, http2

Is there a reason why `http/2.0` for self hosted services (e.g. `Asp.net webapi 2`) is limited to Windows 10 using `built-in .net` functions?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "using .net", if you mean "using the built-in .NET framework classes" then probably because they use OS functionality to do the actual heavy lifting that is only available in Windows 10 (this is just a guess mind you). If you mean "implemented in .net" then obviously anyone can create a working HTTP/2.0 implementation in .NET.

Comment: Yep, I mean the built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, one have to use additional reverse proxy, which supports HTTP/2 to provide .Net web servers via HTTP/2. You can consider to use nginx web server, for example. The solution could looks like on the picture below

[image]

see [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/7-tips-for-faster-http2-performance/)